# Docker build failing inside Azure Dev Ops Self Hosted Agent

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

### Background

I have set up some Self Hosted, Azure Devops build agents, inside my AKS cluster. This is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

The agents have been successfully created, I can see them in my Agent Pools and target them from my pipeline.

One of the first things my pipeline does, is build and push some docker images. This is a problem inside a self hosted agent. The documentation includes the below warning and link:

> In order to use Docker from within a Docker container, you bind-mount the Docker socket.
> If you're sure you want to do this, see the bind mount documentation on Docker.com.

### Files

**Kubernetes Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azdevops-deployment
  labels:
    app: azdevops-agent
spec:
  replicas: 1 #here is the configuration for the actual agent always running
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azdevops-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azdevops-agent
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubepodcreation
        image: AKRTestcase.azurecr.io/kubepodcreation:5306
        env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_URL
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_TOKEN
          - name: AZP_POOL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_POOL
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-volume
      volumes:
      - name: docker-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

### Error

Attempting to run the pipeline gives me the following error:

##errorUnhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

### Questions

1. Is it possible (and safe) to build and push docker images from an Azure Devops build agent running in a docker container?
2. How can I modify the Kubernetes deployment file, to bind mount the docker socket.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.